# Password protect dropdown menu on google sheets. (javascript)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm a total noob when it comes to javascript unfortunately thats what google sheets is using. what i am tasked with is to password protect a drop down menu (data validation) on my google sheets file. so when they try to select their name it asks them for a password, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*With data validation, no this is not possible. You could in theory write an Apps Script workaround but anyone with edit access to the sheet would be able to see the passwords so it would be useless as a protection.*

#### Simple Example:

You'll want to make a data validation dropdown on a cell like normal:

[image]

and then write an onEdit function to run when the value is changed:

```
// define each user password (this is insecure and not recommended)
const userPasswords = { 
  "Name 1": "password1",
  "Name 2": "anotherPassword",
  "Name 3": "insecureIsMyMiddleName",
  "Name 4": "name4nocapitalsorspaces"
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const namesCell = "C2" // the cell with the dropdown
  
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() != namesCell) {
    return
  }

  // show prompt for password:
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  const response = ui.prompt("Password protected range", 
    "Please enter your password:",
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)

  const button = response.getSelectedButton()
  const text = response.getResponseText() 

  // don't run if the user pressed cancel or close
  if (button != ui.Button.OK) {
    return
  }

  // check the passwords
  if (text != userPasswords[e.value]) {
    ui.alert('Incorrect Password', 'Please try again', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    e.range.setValue(e.oldValue) // reset to old value
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: Hi Raffa, can you please give me a sample of the workaround and i'll see if i could use it, the file users are also total noob to google sheets they just know how to insert data into the file.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service, but I'll write up a simple example for you to modify for your needs. If you have trouble with it then I would suggest asking a new question.

Comment: For your own understanding, I recommend checking out [onEdit triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite), [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) for finding out a cell's value when it-s edited, and [prompt dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) for getting user input.